# How to disable the certificate validation on android for ssl connection

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, sslhandshakeexception

I am trying to establish a ssl handshake from my android application which is the client to the server. I am working on an internal network and I trust the server and just for testing purposes I want to disable the certificate validation. How can I do that ?

Comment: So why use SSL at all? If you don't want/need it secure, use plain text.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6378872/49489

Comment: @EJP the final application will utilize SSL. I am still in basic implementation phase and just for testing purposes needed to disable the certificate validation. Anyhow installed the certificate manually in the simulator.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63503375/6639353